# Terraform route table association with VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**I'm having an issue using terraform (cloud) when associating vpc endpoint to routes**

VPC ENDPOINT

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3_endpoint_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.edcelvistacom_vpc.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.region}.s3"
  tags = {
    "Name"    = "VPC Endpoint S3 - for Private Resources"
    "Project" = "edcelvistacom"
    "Env"     = "Production"
  }
}
```

ROUTE ASSOCIATION

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" "application" {
  count = length(var.availability_zones)

  route_table_id  = element(aws_route_table.application.*.id, count.index)
  vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3_endpoint_gateway.id
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error: Provider produced inconsistent result after apply

When applying changes to
module.networking.aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association.application[1],
provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" produced an unexpected new
value: Root resource was present, but now absent.

This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own
issue tracker.
```

Comment: What is your aws provider version?

Comment: Terraform v0.14.5
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v2.70.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws 2.70` is very old. This issue has been already [reported on github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9987) and it seems it [has been fixed](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9987#issuecomment-816360878) in `aws 3.36`. Thus I would try with latest version `3.40` and if the error persists then make a new github issue with the details.

Comment: Solved with Terraform v0.14.5
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.40.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0